# Where to get anti slip treads for walkways?

Tags: construction, materials, building, walkway

I've tried looking for the following in HomeDepot, Amazon and various online supply stores but can't seem to find this exact product. I have seen this used as pedestrian walkway dividers in streets and in airports/schools. Attached is a picture.

[image: Treads]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

DW Dots
dwdots.com

uline.com

Armor-Tile Tactile Systems
armor-tile.com

I'm not sure if they are considered "slip resistant ". I think they're primarily used for ADA tactile surface for the blind.